Generating jar file and deploying it to Jenkins Android
been trying to generate Jar file of my existing Jetpack Compose project.
I want to:

Build jar file
Upload that build to Jenkins Server.

I want to know, what is the correct way of doing it.
I have been trying with this, but it still fails.
android {
    namespace = "com.xxx.xxx"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.xxx.xxx"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    tasks.withType<Jar> {
        enabled = true
        manifest {
            attributes["Main-Class"] = namespace
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.appcompat)
    implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.runtime.ktx)
        ...
}
        // Task to create a JAR file
    task createJar(type: Jar) {
        archiveBaseName = 'mycomposeapp'
        archiveVersion = '1.0.0'
        from {
            configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
        }
        with jar
    }

Any help here, please?
Can set up Jenkins file, but what to do in build.gradle is what making me mad :(


Akash can you post your complete gradle file and where are you calling createJar task ?

@BobSmith,
android {
compileSdk = 34
defaultConfig {
applicationId = "com.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx"
minSdk = 24
}
buildTypes {..}
compileOptions {
sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
kotlinOptions {jvmTarget = "1.8"}
}
dependencies {
implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)    implementation(libs.androidx.appcompat)
implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.runtime.ktx)
...
}
task jar (type: Jar) {
archiveBaseName = 'your-jar-name'
archiveVersion = '1.0'
from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
include 'xxx.xxx'
}

@BobSmith, Done... Edited my question

Akash line no 34 having 3 dots did you copied it from somewhere. Don't use unnecessary dots, commas and brackets it will break your system. Learn how groovy gradle works. If its difficult switch to Kotlin Based DSL

@BobSmith I have removed most of the business codes from the Gradle... Also the issue is with creating Jar which I'm not able to :(
